# Plot dataset below using python datafram

Tags: python, dataframe, plot

I have dataset as below each row represent a customer ID and column is time and value for a month for every 30 min, I can't plot that in time line graph

[image]

I want to convert it as below
[image]

any advise

trying...............

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.wide_to_long`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) to make this kind of reshape :

```
df.columns= df.columns.str.replace("\s+", "", regex=True)

out = (
        pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['Time', 'value'], i='ID',  j='_')
              .droplevel(1, axis=0)
              .reset_index()
              .sort_values(by='ID')
              .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   ID            Time  value
0   1  1/12/2020 0:00      1
1   1  1/12/2020 0:30     10
2   1  1/12/2020 1:00     15
3   1  1/12/2020 1:30     20
4   1  1/12/2020 2:00      4
5   2  1/12/2020 0:00      3
6   2  1/12/2020 0:30      3
7   2  1/12/2020 1:00      4
8   2  1/12/2020 1:30      6
9   2  1/12/2020 2:00      5
```

Then, you can use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) to get the desired plot :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

plt.plot(out['Time'], out['value'])
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

[image]